# Appwrite issue for connecting

Tags: reactjs, appwrite

Error

> User getCurrentuser : AppwriteException: User (role: guests) missing scope (account)
> at Client.

My code:

```
import { Client,Account,ID } from "appwrite";
export class AuthService{
    client=new Client();
    account;
    constructor(){
        this.client
        .setEndpoint(conf.appwriteURL)
        .setProject(conf.appwrite_projectID);
        this.account = new Account(this.client);
    }
async getCurrentUser()
    {
        try{
            return await this.account.get();
        }
        catch(e)
        { console.log("USer getCurrentuser :",e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I am using appwrite for a backend for my React app. How can I resolve this issue, and how can I add role in appwrite?

Answer (score 0):

that just means you're not logged in yet :)

This approach is correct, you check to see if you're logged in, if not, redirect to login page in the catch.

You can create a session in a variety of ways, email pass, anonymous, phone auth, etc.

https://appwrite.io/docs/products/auth/quick-start